# elasticsearch filters aggregation does not return array format

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

The [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) returns bucket as object

```
      "buckets": {
        "errors": {
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        "warnings": {
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      }
```

But i would like to return a buckets array, like the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html?msclkid=f5bab7ecb42411ecbca2ddbddef391c8)

```
      "buckets": [
        { 
          "key": "errors",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        { 
          "key": "warnings",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
```

Is this possible or any sort of data transformation can be done in the query to make it so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by providing an [array of filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html#_anonymous_filters), but in this case your buckets will be anonymous:

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : [    <--- specify array
          { "match" : { "body" : "error"   }},
          { "match" : { "body" : "warning" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will provide an array of resulting buckets in the same order

```
  "buckets": [
    {
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "doc_count": 2
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the anonymous filters but i would need to have the key mapped to the doc_count unfortunately